# Can I fix a broken notebook keyboard connector?

Tags: keyboard, netbook

It´s the HP Mini 110 (which is a netbook) keyboard. I took it out, not very carefully, and the black input separated from the plastic membrane (I don´t know if that´s the word, my native language is Spanish, and we call it "membrana"). Watch the photo, and you will understand. Can I fix that? How? or I have to buy a new keyboard?

Taken with a 2MP camera:

[image]

Comment: You broke the connector.  You would need to replace the entire cable and the connector.  Somebody with more skilled hands then yourself might be able to solve the problem for you though.

Comment: Is the connector actually broken or will it clip back onto the keyboard?  I think this connector is just a plastic clip that holds the strip in place on the motherboard/keyboard and should not be attached to the strip at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my father fixed it. The "membrane", as I call it, had to touch the low part of the output, and the putted the black plastic to make it stay static. And now works!